# How do I go about centering my drop-down nav menu?

Tags: html, css

I’m trying to figure out how to reposition the entire `<ul>` element to the center of the screen, yet every time I try a new method the drop-down items get jumbled up by either shifting slightly to the right or they lay on top of one another.

Can someone lend a hand, let me know what I’m doing wrong and give me some tips to make it a bit easier?

Here’s what I’m working with.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.menu ul {
  /*This is blank because nothing I tried works*/
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  font-family: cursive;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you want it to always center go for % rather than px

Comment: Thanks for the tip I mainly use px since I understand it a little better than % but i'll work toward using % more often

Comment: px just does pixels in the screen.  % does the entire length of the screen.  For example 100% is the entire screen length.  So if you wanted to split up 5 nav bars (in theory) 20% would make each one 20% of the screen size ie one fifth of your screen.  This is useful because it allows you to keep content 'under control' no matter the screen size.

Comment: that helps a bunch thanks for the explanation! It definitely seems more efficient to use %, I definitely had the wrong idea about using the px value. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Add this code to your UL tag, it should center the whole thing